# Problem exposing port with Docker swarm and windows containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run a container in docker swarm mode using `docker stack deploy`. I have read quite a lot of things about exposing ports of deployed services in docker swarm for **windows** containers, but none of them work for me.

I am trying to access a container from my local machine and the swarm stack is deployed on the same machine.

I have tried

```
        deploy:
            mode: global
        ports:
            - target: 80
              published: 8080
              mode: host
```

but that does not work. In this case it seems like the container fails to start and new containers are being created immediately. How can I inspect and see what the reason for  the crashing is? When I do docker container ls no results are returned.

I have also tried to assign an external NAT network but this does not seem to work and I get the following message

> network is declared as external, but it is not in the right scope: "local" instead of "swarm"

so I cannot attach to it.

Using

```
        deploy:
            endpoint_mode: dnsrr
```

has no results, as well. What I do in this case is to look at the IP when getting into the service, but for an IP address I get 10.0.7.2 which does not allow me to connect to the service from my host.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some tips what I am doing wrong and how I can access my own container in a docker swarm service from my machine.
I have been stuck for quite a while and I am probably missing some important bits.

Comment: its not clear how you are trying to access the container from the host machine and whats failing.

Comment: I am both trying to access it using localhost:8080 if I am trying to expose the port or access the site using the local IP, which I grab from the container when I inspect it. Unfortunately when I deploy using docker stack deploy -c with mode: global and             endpoint_mode: dnsrr, the IP of the container is 10.0.1.2, which I believe is local to the swarm network, so I cannot access it.

Comment: The 10.0 address will be particularly useless. The port you are publishing is 6001, not 8080, and its not clear what port the service is listening on in the container. Hopefully 80.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me, Chris. I have edited my question a bit. I am trying to connect to port 8080. When I deploy it using the command `docker service create --name=testservice --mode global --publish published=8080,target=80,protocol=tcp,mode=host --env-file theEnvFile  mycontainer` it works. When I try to do it with docker stack deploy it does not:
    deploy:  mode: global 
  ports:  - target: 80     published: 8080       mode : host 

The service within the stack keeps crashing and new ones are being created